# Is there a way to select the same channel across multiple controllers in one go?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

Let's say I'm animating a character and I'm working on a blink and would therefore like to animate the Trans. Z of the eyelids. I'm looking for a way (preferably in the graph editor) to select both trans. z channels of the eyelid controllers at once, without having to manually select one trans. z channel of say the left eyelid controller and then having to go down the list of all channels to find and shift-select the trans. z channel of the right eyelid controller. I guess what I'm looking for is something similar to the maya attribute editor, where selecting one attribute (the equivalent of channels in maya) selects that attribute for all selected controllers at once. It's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

in the graph editor, just select the channels you want to edit.

Then press I in the graph editor -> only selected channels

[image]

Comment: thanks, but if I want to edit the same channel on both objects, is there a way to select them both with one click, or so I have to select them manually one after the other?

Comment: i don't know about a way selecting this with one click....

Answer (score 0):

Blender doesn't support selecting a certain channel across objects.

Fortunately, you can install the [Highlight Channels](https://github.com/j3soon/blender-highlight-channels) addon to achieve this with hotkeys:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Highlight Channels addon.